# Test simple JDBC database access

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, testing, jdbc

I have a project where I connect to an Oracle database via simple plain JDBC. For testing my data access layer, I thought about creating an in-memory database (Hyper SQL, ...). My question now is: How do I get JDBC to connect to the right database depending on if it is a test or just normal execution?

I want a database, which sets itself up before tests. The queries should then be fired on the testing database instead of the normal one. After tests are finished, the testing database should be torn down.

Here is the way I connect to the database:

```
Class.forName(DRIVER_STRING);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

And this how I execute my queries:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
statement.setLong(1, id);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: what is exactly the question? do note, that the jdbc/odbc bridge has been removed from Java 8

Comment: I want to know how i can achieve that JDBC automatically knows which database to connect to (test/normal execution)

Comment: For example: encapsulate connection string, username and password into a separate class, that makes them available via getters; in test provide a test-specific instance of that class...

Comment: That's actually a great idea, not sure why I didn't come up with it myself.

Is it possible to setup the database at the beginning of the class? Which database would you suggest using?

Comment: The database you should use depends on your system and your requirements, this is not something you should let people "guess" about